# Can I run FuelPHP Task in single process ?

Tags: php, linux, fuelphp

I want to run FuelPHP Task every minute by cron.
But I don't want to run duplicate FuelPHP Task.

Do you have any idea ?

I tried to control by pid, But getmypid() return same value always...

Comment: you can write a script that 1st check previous instance of fulephp is running or not, if running get pid and kill it. add the script to cron job for every minute

Comment: thank you for your response. How do you know previous instance of fuelphp is running ? please ?

Comment: how do you run the tasks? `getmypid` should work. where do you call it?

Comment: I am using FuelPHP Tasks. oil refine my_task_name. And I wrote getmypid in "public function run()" . getmypid result is always 5000.

Comment: that's very strange. if you were somehow running the tasks from browser, than obviously the problem would've been that the webserver's pid is returned, which doesn't change between requests. but if you run `oil refine task_name` from terminal (or from cron), that that should always be a new process. I tried creating an empty task, and running it, which resulted showing different pid every time... the problem should be in your setup, I guess.

Comment: I am so sorry Barta. I used getmygid !! Now , I can get pid . Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is (if you don't need to send data to your process, but it reads the data itself (eg. from database)) you can use a process manager with a long running task (basically in an infinite loop). (Actually you also need a process manager in a queue-based solution as well, since it requires workers on the receiver side)

I usually use [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for this purpose.

A simple, long running application:

```
while (true) {
    // do something
    sleep(1);
}
```

The advantage of supervisord is that it can restart your process if it stops for some reason.

Comment: Thanks mark. It is one of the idea to solve my problems.

Answer (score 0):

For such tasks, your best option might be to use some sort of queuing system. I found the best looking [Bernard](https://github.com/bernardphp/bernard). You should take a look.

(**Edit:** I made an assumption about your task based on your need to have them not to overlap, and that's why I recommended queues. If it's something new to you, take a look at them, and decide which is better for you, if it doesn't fit best for you, someone searching for single task keywords may still find queues useful, so I leave it in the answer.)

If your environment doesn't allow such a solution for some reason, or you truly simply need a method to tell if the previous process is running, or not, you should just create a lockfile in the temp directory, something like `mytask.lock` when a task starts, and delete it when it terminates (finishes, or crashes). You can then check if the file is present.

This is a common solution for this problem, but using queue systems is much more flexible, and much more elegant.

Other possibility is to use pidfiles, which are not empty, but store the process ID of the first running task, so you can even terminate that, or send messages to it. Same with lockfiles, you put it in your temp directory, and name it like `mytask.pid` (or whatever you want, but `*.pid` is common).

Comment: For the latter case https://packagist.org/packages/liip/process-manager can be a solution. It tries to emulate some sort of high level mutex locking (at low level it does exactly that by using flock).